# Tomcat error on AWS: org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have a big problem with maven, tomcat 8 and AWS.

I have a java based web page and everything is working fine, when I'm using it local. But, when I try to upload to AWS I get this error message:

```
20-Aug-2018 20:56:52.010 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1125)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1868)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Two weeks ago everything was working, now I can't deploy anything. If I go back to some older version then it's working.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Is it java version/tomcat version incompatibility?

Comment: It was working before with the same config. Tomcat 8 and Java 8

Comment: There should be some more information in the logs than what you're showing.  I would encourage you to take a bit deeper look.

Comment: I'm new in this server thing so I don't know what to look for. This is the last 100 line log:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lGnsVqheU_Bh0TSRrZ-fEtoaWQvyghaB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It looks like your `web.xml` is not correct as there is at least one error coming from it.  The first is `The servlets named [szabadsag.saveSzabadsag] and [WebOldal.saveSzabadsag] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/saveSzabadsag] which is not permitted`.  Can you post your `web.xml`?

Comment: Thanks but I saw that, and solved that issue. The deploy after that was the problem. Around this time: 
[21/Aug/2018:18:04]

Comment: According to your log file that error occurs **after** the date you mentioned.  We're going to need a bit more to go on as your question indicates that there is a "before" and "after" state.  You'll need to know what has changed between those two times and rollback things one by one.

Comment: You were right. I deleted the files, but didn't delete from target directory. Pls send it as answer